# GROUP BY with all combinations of columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to figure out how to write a single select that would give me all combinations of values for certain aggregations.

Let me give you an example of data:

```
COUNTRY  PRODUCT  VALUE
cz       p1       5
cz       p2       10
de       p1       8
de       p2       15
```

Let's say I would like to get `SUM` of values grouped by certain criteria for all possible combinations with two column values. The catch is, that `ALL` values is also an option:

```
COUNTRY  PRODUCT  SUM(VALUE)
cz       p1       5
cz       p2       10
de       p1       8
de       p2       15
cz       ALL      15
de       ALL      23
ALL      p1       13
ALL      p2       25
ALL      ALL      38
```

I know I can do this using multiple selects with different groupBy conditions like

```
SELECT "COUNTRY", "PRODUCT", SUM("VALUE") FROM "PRODUCTS"
SELECT "COUNTRY", "PRODUCT", SUM("VALUE") FROM "PRODUCTS" GROUP BY ("COUNTRY", "PRODUCT")
SELECT "COUNTRY", "PRODUCT", SUM("VALUE") FROM "PRODUCTS" GROUP BY ("COUNTRY")
SELECT "COUNTRY", "PRODUCT", SUM("VALUE") FROM "PRODUCTS" GROUP BY ("PRODUCT")
```

and combine the results.

But I wonder it it is possible to optimize this and select these combinations with single query. Sorry if this has been answered already, I did not find it.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: it is all about GROPUNG_SETS https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-grouping-sets/

Comment: @Sergey Thank you! I feel dumb now. This solution with `UNION`  and `GROUPING SETS` is very elegant. Can't believe I did not think of it. You can wirte is as an asnwer, sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `CUBE`:

```
SELECT country, product, SUM(value)
FROM products
GROUP BY CUBE(country, product)
ORDER BY country NULLS LAST, product NULLS LAST;
```

Comment: this is actually even better, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is about GROUPING_SETS-clause
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-grouping-sets/

Answer (score 0):

If your data is hierarchical (you want to analyze the data by country, or all countries combined, but not the total of each products), prefer the "GROUP BY ROLLUP" over the "GROUP BY CUBE" clause.

```
SELECT country, product, SUM(value)
FROM products
GROUP BY CUBE(country, product)
ORDER BY country NULLS LAST, product NULLS LAST;

| country | product | SUM |
|---------|---------|-----|
| cz      | p1      | 5   |
| cz      | p2      | 10  |
| cz      | NULL    | 15  |
| de      | p1      | 8   |
| de      | p2      | 15  |
| de      | NULL    | 23  |
| NULL    | p1      | 13  |
| NULL    | p2      | 25  |
| NULL    | NULL    | 38  |
```

or

```
SELECT country, product, SUM(value)
FROM products
GROUP BY ROLLUP(country, product)
ORDER BY country NULLS LAST, product NULLS LAST;

| country | product | SUM |
|---------|---------|-----|
| cz      | p1      | 5   |
| cz      | p2      | 10  |
| cz      | NULL    | 15  |
| de      | p1      | 8   |
| de      | p2      | 15  |
| de      | NULL    | 23  |
| NULL    | NULL    | 38  |
```